# Rails method call on active record relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have what to call a method in model from controller, where controller has active record relation object

like

```
@paid_drivers = DriverInvoice.where(driver_id: current_affilate_company.drivers.pluck(:id))
```

where I got

```
>     <ActiveRecord::Relation [#<DriverInvoice id: 1, driver_id: 13, total_reservations: 2, total_from_reservations: 20.0, pay: 20.5,
> discount_amount: 0.0, other_amount: 0.5, tax: 0.0, created_at:
> "2016-02-03 05:14:56", updated_at: "2016-02-03 05:14:56",
> payment_type: 1, is_other_addition: true, is_tax_per: true, tax_value:
> nil>, #<DriverInvoice id: 2, driver_id: 56, total_reservations: 3,
> total_from_reservations: 452.0, pay: 452.0, discount_amount: 0.0,
> other_amount: 0.0, tax: 0.0, created_at: "2016-02-03 05:15:36",
> updated_at: "2016-02-03 05:15:36", payment_type: 1, is_other_addition:
> true, is_tax_per: true, tax_value: nil>]>
```

now  on that obj. I want a method call 
    @paid_drivers =   @paid_drivers.search_paid_driver()

and in my model

```
def self.search_paid_driver()
 raise self.inspect
end
```

That give only table fields

like

> DriverInvoice(id: integer, driver_id: integer, total_reservations:
>   integer, total_from_reservations: float, pay: float, discount_amount:
>   float, other_amount: float, tax: float, created_at: datetime,
>   updated_at: datetime, payment_type: integer, is_other_addition:
>   boolean, is_tax_per: boolean, tax_value: float)

I want all recoreds of @paid_drivers so I can process them further in my model.

How can I do that pls help.

Comment: Do you want load all paid drivers into memory? Just `@paid_drivers = DriverInvoice.where(driver_id: current_affilate_company.drivers.pluck(:id)).all`. But you should let it in lazy loading

Comment: @LongNuyen  can you please elaborate your answer

Comment: But what do you want?

Comment: i want to put the further filters on the object i have got as @paid_driver

Comment: Ah, you can use `scope`. Here is document http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [active record scope](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope) for yo

```
class DriverInvoice
  scope :for_company, -> (company) { where(driver_id: current_affilate_company.drivers.pluck(:id))}
end

@paid_drivers = DriverInvoice.for_company(current_affilate_company)
```

Then you can use other filters by defining other `scope`s or using `where` chain

Answer (score 2):

`self` inside `self.search_paid_driver()` is the `DriverInvoice` class, not the `ActiveRelation` instance. So, what you got as output is right.

I would suggest using a scope for this kind of query.

Still if you want to achieve same with class method, it should be something like this:

```
def self.search_paid_driver(current_affiliate_company)
    .where(driver_id: current_affiliate_company.drivers.pluck(:id))
end
```

Or if you can manage `current_affiliate_company` from inside the class, you can omit the method param.

Comment: what abt if i pass @paid_drivers to the search_paid_driver method in model from controller, I mean isn't that a rails way